# Today's rep changes not shown in Achivements menu

Tags: bug

When I open the Achievements menu it's not showing any of the rep I've earned today:

[image]

Here's my Reputation tab showing I've earned 85 rep today:

[image]

The Android app's Achievements menu is also missing today's rep. I tried from another browser with the same result.

What's going on?